# OpenJPA cache vs ehcache plugin

Tags: caching, jpa-2.0, ehcache, openjpa

openjpa comes with its own cache implementation. But it will also easily integrate with ehcache and other third-party cache providers.

What are the main advantages of using ehcache vs OpenJPA's implementation? is it a scalability issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ehcache can run in a distributed mode which is more scalable and the default OpenJPA cache implementation is limited by the size of the JVM's memory. I believe that running with the default cache you will see much better performance that running with a distributed ehcache.